# Селектор для Item RecycleView

Tags: android

Есть такой селектор

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/colorAccent" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
</selector>
```

Можно ли его применить для элемента RecyclerView, чтобы в обычном состоянии был второй цвет, а при нажатии/касании/удержании как в ListView менялся на другой цвет?

В качестве фона для CardView указал данный селектор но не помогло